# PrimeNG tree selection empty array shows two 'No result message'

Tags: angular, primeng

I added stackblitz link. But I don't understand why empty message shows two times.

```
selectedItem: any[] = [];
testArray: any[] = [];

<div class="card">
  <h5>Checkbox</h5>
     <p-treeSelect [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [options]="testArray" selectionMode="checkbox" 
      placeholder="Select Item">
     </p-treeSelect>
```

```
enter code here
```

[stackblitz example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treeselect-demo-ndxxg6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. It is not perfect but it can hide child or `p-tree` items empty messages.

```
.p-treeselect-panel .p-treeselect-items-wrapper .p-treeselect-empty-message {
    display: none;
}
```